# Generated Markup in Datatable

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, wicket

When creating a DataTable in Wicket and adding a Toolbar like this:

```
grid = new DataTable(...);
grid.addTopToolbar(new AjaxFallbackHeadersToolbar(grid, dataProvider));
```

The resulting Markup is displayed in IE 10+ like this:

```
<table wicket:id="table">
 <thead> ... </thead>
 <tbody> ... </tbody>
</table>
```

But in IE 8 and 9 the markup displayed is:

```
<table wicket:id="table">
  <panel xlmns:wicket="">
    <thead> [other panel and container elements in here too] </thead>
    <tbody> ... </tbody>
  </panel>
</table>
```

I have wicket-devmode activated and assume in livemode those panels and containers will be gone but it is nevertheless very annoying that the markup is erroneus, which also leads to strange quirks when displaying the table.

there is no problem in firefox and IE 7 and IE 10+ (tested with IE compatibility mode of developer tools)

when i do not add the toolbar the problem does not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable wicket tags/attributes in your application's init method:

```
getMarkupSettings.setStripWicketTags(true);
```

Comment: that solves the problem but does not answer why the markup is there in the first place.

Comment: @thg I think it is there in development mode to help with debugging, otherwise you couldn't easily tell which component was associated with which markup.